# Shared arraylist between two activity doesn't work

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity, android-arrayadapter

I have a problem, when I select my items in checkedbox ( so it become checked) the array had filled, but when I click on "Done" is called the new activity GenreViewActivity that called a method for getting the arraylist of the previous activity, but its ListView, the layout is empty. What am I wrong?

[AccountActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQPyM.jpg)
[GenreViewActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvM2P.jpg)

AccountActivity.java:

```
package com.example.msnma.movienotifier;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    private static ArrayList <String> itemsChkStr = new ArrayList<String();

public class Item 
{
        boolean checked;
        Drawable ItemDrawable;
        String ItemString;
        Item(/*Drawable drawable,*/ String t, boolean b)
        {
            //ItemDrawable = drawable;
            ItemString = t;
            checked = b;
        }

        public boolean isChecked()
        {
            return checked;
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder 
    {
        CheckBox checkBox;
        ImageView icon;
        TextView text;
    }

    public class ItemsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
    {

        private Context context;
        private List<Item> list;

        ItemsListAdapter(Context c, List<Item> l) 
        {
            context = c;
            list = l;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() 
        {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) 
        {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }

        public boolean isChecked(int position) 
        {
            return list.get(position).checked;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            View rowView = convertView;

            // reuse views
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            if (rowView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) 
                 context).getLayoutInflater();
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

                viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) 
                 rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowCheckBox);
                //viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) 
                   rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowImageView);
                viewHolder.text = (TextView) 
                   rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
                rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
                } 
                else 
                {
                 viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
                }

            //viewHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(list.get(position).ItemDrawable);
            viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(list.get(position).checked);

            final String itemStr = list.get(position).ItemString;
            viewHolder.text.setText(itemStr);

            viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(position);

            /*
            viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
                    new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton 
                     compoundButton, boolean b) 
                {
                    list.get(position).checked = b;

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            itemStr + "onCheckedChanged\nchecked: " + b,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            */

            viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new 
                  View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    boolean newState = !list.get(position).isChecked();
                    list.get(position).checked = newState;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            itemStr + "setOnClickListener\nchecked: " + newState,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(isChecked(position));

            return rowView;
        }
    }

    Button btnLookup;
    Button btnDone;
    List<Item> items;
    ListView listView;
    ItemsListAdapter myItemsListAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        btnLookup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.lookup);
        btnDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done);

        initItems();
        myItemsListAdapter = new ItemsListAdapter(this, items);
        listView.setAdapter(myItemsListAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(AccountActivity.this,
                        ((Item)(parent.getItemAtPosition(position))).ItemString,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }});

        //Arraylist di tipo stringa con elementi checked

        for (int i=0; i<items.size(); i++){
            if (items.get(i).isChecked()){
                //str += i + "\n";
                itemsChkStr.add(items.get(i).ItemString);
            }
        }

        btnLookup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String str = "Check items:\n";

                for (int i=0; i<items.size(); i++){
                    if (items.get(i).isChecked()){
                        //str += i + "\n";
                        str += items.get(i).ItemString;
                    }
                }

                /*
                int cnt = myItemsListAdapter.getCount();
                for (int i=0; i<cnt; i++){
                    if(myItemsListAdapter.isChecked(i)){
                        str += i + "\n";
                    }
                }
                */

                Toast.makeText(AccountActivity.this,
                        str,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }

    private void initItems(){
        items = new ArrayList<Item>();

        TypedArray arrayDrawable = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.resicon);
        TypedArray arrayText = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.restext);

        for(int i=0; i<arrayDrawable.length(); i++){
            //Drawable d = arrayDrawable.getDrawable(i);
            String s = arrayText.getString(i);
            boolean b = false;
            Item item = new Item(/*d,*/ s, b);
            items.add(item);
        }

        arrayDrawable.recycle();
        arrayText.recycle();
    }

    public void pressDoneButton(View view)
    {
        //itemsChecks();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GenreViewActivity.class);
        //EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        //String message = editText.getText().toString();
        //intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    /*public ArrayList <String> itemsChecks()
    {
        ArrayList <String> arrGenre = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=0; i<items.size(); i++){
            if (items.get(i).isChecked()){
                arrGenre.add(items.get(i).toString());
            }
        }
        viewArray(arrGenre);

    }*/

    public static ArrayList <String> getSelectedString(){
        return itemsChkStr;
    }

}
    /*@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        // Get a support ActionBar corresponding to this toolbar
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();

        // Enable the Up button
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_second, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void pressAccountButton(MenuItem item) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AccountActivity.class);
        //EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        //String message = editText.getText().toString();
        //intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }*/
```

GenreViewActivity:

```
package com.example.msnma.movienotifier;


import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GenreViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //AccountActivity aa = new AccountActivity();

    private ListView lv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_genre_view);
        lv = findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // Instanciating an array list (you don't need to do this,
        // you already have yours).
        ArrayList<String> your_array_list; //= new ArrayList<String>();
        /*your_array_list.add("foo");
        your_array_list.add("bar");*/

        your_array_list = AccountActivity.getSelectedString();





        // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a
        // first parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your
        // array as a third parameter.
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                your_array_list);

        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);


    }

}
    /*@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_genre_view);
    }*/
```

activity_genre_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".GenreViewActivity">

 <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:text="Genre"
     android:textStyle="bold" />
 <!--android:autoLink="web"-->

 <ListView
     android:id="@+id/listview"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="544dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you please clean up your code. remove the commented out code

Comment: @user47845 You need to add this line `itemsChkStr.add(list.get(position).ItemString);` under `checkBox.setOnClickListener  Method`.

Answer (score 5):

Use **putStringArrayListExtra** to pass ArrayList.

```
public void pressDoneButton(View view)
    {
        //itemsChecks();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GenreViewActivity.class);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("your_list",itemsChkStr);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

and use `intent.getStringArrayListExtra("your_list");` to get ArrayList.

In your GenreViewActivity...

```
if(getIntent()!=null){
your_array_list = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("your_list");
}
```

Comment: It really is :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will be empty. You fill your static array itemsChkStr just only in begin before that you try to put check. You need to update your static checked list after each checked action.